# How to prevent <Esc> from waiting for more input in Insert Mode

Tags: vim, configuration, keyboard-shortcuts

When I leave insert mode by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, there is a half-second pause before Vim actually returns to normal mode.

Normally this wouldn't be an issue, since pressing a normal mode command like <kbd>j</kbd> after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> executes the normal-mode command immediately (without the above-mentioned wait), but I have the mapping `inoremap <Esc> <Esc>:w<CR>`, so that every time I leave insert mode the file is written. I would like the write to occur *immediately* when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but instead there is that half-second pause.

I'm assuming that the pause is because Vim is waiting for more input before it decides that I just meant to type a single, simple <kbd>Esc</kbd>. This must be because there is a mapping somewhere who's first character is `<Esc>`, but I've looked in my `.vimrc` and there is no such mapping.

Furthermore, I even ran `:map <Esc>`, and it returned `No such mapping`. So, if there is no such mapping, why does Vim appear to be waiting for more input, and how can I avoid that behavior?

---

**Extra Information**

It appears that this is not reproduceable, so here is some more information in case anyone really wants to get to the bottom of this:

I am using [Steve Francia's `spf13` distribution of Vim](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim), with [my own `.vimrc.local` on top of it](https://gist.github.com/4080745). I have also installed [several additional plugins](https://gist.github.com/4053482) using Vundle.

*Notes:* `.vimrc.local` is sourced last in `.vimrc`.

Comment: I tried this mapping in my .vimrc but found no discernable delay... so I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Magnus, thanks, guess it must be due to my particular config. See the edit for more info on that.

Comment: Are you sure the pause isn't the time it takes to write the file?

Comment: @Dan, fairly sure. The pause is about 5-6 times the length of the pause that occurs when writing a file normally.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### UPDATE (3/19/2014)

I found a far better solution than trying to hunt down all the mappings that start with `<Esc>`, courtesy of [Powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline), from the [Tips & Tricks](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tipstricks.html) section of the docs. Put this somewhere in your `.vimrc`:

```
 " leave insert mode quickly
  if ! has('gui_running')
    set ttimeoutlen=10
    augroup FastEscape
      autocmd!
      au InsertEnter * set timeoutlen=0
      au InsertLeave * set timeoutlen=1000
    augroup END
  endif
```

Note that this will make it impossible to use mappings that start with `<Esc>` while in insert mode, but there shouldn't be any of those anyway, because of the problem this solves.

---

I found the lines in spf13's `.vimrc` that were causing the problem:

```
" Fix home and end keybindings for screen, particularly on mac
" - for some reason this fixes the arrow keys too. huh.
map ^[F $
imap ^[F $
map ^[H g0
imap ^[H g0
```

The reason I couldn't find them before is because they weren't mapped using `<Esc>`, but `^[` instead. Very irritating! Hope this helps some equally disgruntled spf13 user :)

**UPDATE:**

If removing those mappings doesn't work, then it's probably a mapping from a plugin.

Type `:verbose map <Esc>` to get a list of all mappings involving <kbd>Esc</kbd>. The `verbose` part instructs Vim to print where the mapping was set. That should help find out what's causing the problem.

Also, the command `unmap <Esc>` might be useful—it removes any mappings for the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Note that `unmap` does not remove mappings in all modes; type `:h unmap` for more info.

Comment: I am using spf13 and deleting those lines doesnt work. I tried to unmap in vimrc.local file. How did you solve it? I am using vim in gnome terminal and the workaround to fix Alt mapping doesn't work if ESC key is mapped like that.

Comment: for those who still seek for solution:
set timeoutlen=0 " Time to wait after ESC (default causes an annoying delay)
from [link](https://github.com/lucascaton/spf13-vim-customization/blob/master/.vimrc.local)

Comment: @navie, I believe that will cause Vim never to wait for additional input in case there are ambiguous mappings, which might be problematic for many people. For instance, if you have mappings for `j` and `jj`, Vim won't wait to see if you type `j` twice, so the second mapping will be effectively removed. See my updated answer for a different fix.

Comment: This approach only seems to work for the gui version. Terminal vim is still slow exiting insert mode using <C-[>.

Comment: @btiernay, if this is still a problem for you, try the updated solution—seems to work reliably for me in both gui and terminal vim.

Comment: I am so confused. In your 3/19/2014 edit, doesn't that set timeoutlen to 1000 when leaving insert (entering normal), so it solves nothing? Is this logic inverted? I went and inverted the logic myself and it seems like that made it work. I tested an esc-bind and it still went through despite the timeoutlen=0. Not sure why, but I'll take it. An aside: This method also allows me to no longer have to chew up unassigned vim F-keys for fast alt-based shortcuts. Neat.

Comment: I don't think the logic is reversed. The point is to remove the wait time when pressing escape while in Insert Mode, so we want the `timeoutlen` to be 0 while in Insert Mode. So we set it to 0 upon entering Insert Mode and then restore it back to its default value upon leaving.

Comment: Okay, sorry I guess we are trying to address two different issues. The issue you are addressing is that Esc hangs (when using it to exit insert mode). *this is not my issue*. My issue is that Esc hangs in normal mode, and causes my Alt+H bind to fire when I type Esc (in normal mode) and `h` too fast. If you would like, I can delete my comments.

Comment: My answer is for the issue stated in the first sentence of the question.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, it was tmux injecting that delay (this came as a complete surprise for me!).

I fixed it by adding `set -g escape-time 0` to my `tmux.conf`.

---

This may not strictly help the author, but this question comes up first when searching for this issue with many different keyword combinations, so I hope it helps someone.

---

Source: first comment from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15550847/107510).

Answer (score 7):

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is with the mapping you describe, in my opinion it should be fine. However, I think that what you want to accomplish can be reached in a better way. Your mapping is basically an attempt at creating a `InsertLeave` event, which Vim actually already has built in!

Try adding something like this to your `.vimrc`:

```
au InsertLeave * if &mod && expand('%')!=''|write|endif
```

As an added bonus, this one only saves your buffer if it has a filename and was actually modified.

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to do two things on InsertLeave? I'd lik e to write the file and also call `!latexmk -pdf -f`, which is a bash command that compiles the TeX document I'm working on to a pdf.

Comment: You can concatenate Vim commands with `|`, as shown in the answer, or define additional `:autocmd`. As you probably want the autosave for all buffers, but the compile only for TeX, you'd use `:autocmd InsertLeave <buffer> !latexmk ...`, and put that into `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex_autocompile.vim`.

Comment: Another option if you want to do a lot of stuff is to make the autocmd do `call DoMyAutosaveStuff()` and then create a function with that name which contains the stuff you want it to do.  I've started doing a lot of things when the window loses focus and when the file is saved and all of these different things; it's much easier to have the block of autocmds be "simple" function calls and have the actual functionality elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```vim
set timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=0
```

`timeoutlen` - mapping delays.

`ttimeoutlen` - key code delays.

[Source](https://www.johnhawthorn.com/2012/09/vi-escape-delays/#vim)