# How to exit visual mode without a delay in Vim?

Tags: vim

In Vim, when in Visual mode, I have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> twice to exit it and turn off the selection. After one press of <kbd>Esc</kbd> I have to wait 2 seconds for the selection to turn off.

What can I do to exit Visual mode immediately when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed?

Comment: do you have any mapping with ESC key?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Executing following command helped me:

```
set timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=0
```

see: http://www.johnhawthorn.com/2012/09/vi-escape-delays/.

Comment: I wonder why someone has downvoted this answer, as it works fine. I found useful the setting for tmux on the reference: `set -sg escape-time 0`

Comment: @mMontu Omg thank you, I was getting mad trying to figure out why the setting wasn't being used in vim, I had no idea tmux had its own separate setting!

Comment: for me this seemed to manifest itself while using tmux.  The mMontu comment pointed me to the link, which worked wonders

Comment: This does not work when you have any mappings that start with `<Esc>`, you will still have the delay. In my case I have `Alt` and `j` and `k` mapped to move lines and they translate to `<Esc>j` and `<Esc>k`. Really not obvious. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15550787/520061 helped in this case.

Comment: This also removed the delay when doing repeated insert (e.g. `2itext<Esc>`)!

Answer (score 11):

As Ingo explained. Just thought I would post the solution:
https://github.com/Greduan/dotfiles/blob/47f92e4db29d4ead778d877a85082b271de130ed/vim/vimrc.vim#L332-L346

Works pretty well. It's a little bit confusing for me as well, so I can't really explain, but the code explains itself pretty well.

The point is it works, it simply makes `<Esc>` work immediately even when on Terminal. I believe if you do have mappings set to `<Esc>` it'll give you time to do those as well. However I'm not sure.

**EDIT**

Studied a bit and I can now explain it. Basically, if you're not using a GUI (like MacVim) then when you enter insert mode the `ttimeoutlen` will be set to 0. Meaning that as soon as you click `<Esc>` that'll work. However once you're in normal mode then it'll set the `ttimeoutlen` to the number you prefer, letting you do mappings with `<Esc>`.

Perfect solution I think, since if you have mappings in insert mode it'll be using control or something like that.

**EDIT 2**

Here's the code:

```
set timeout " Do time out on mappings and others
set timeoutlen=2000 " Wait {num} ms before timing out a mapping

" When you’re pressing Escape to leave insert mode in the terminal, it will by
" default take a second or another keystroke to leave insert mode completely
" and update the statusline. This fixes that. I got this from:
" https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tipstricks.html#vim
if !has('gui_running')
    set ttimeoutlen=10
    augroup FastEscape
        autocmd!
        au InsertEnter * set timeoutlen=0
        au InsertLeave * set timeoutlen=1000
    augroup END
endif
```

With time I've removed the condition that the GUI isn't running and it still works as far as I can tell.

Comment: what the difference between the 2000ms from the second line and the 1000ms? Thanks!

Comment: @etal not sure honestly. I did this so long ago. :P They're the same option so they could probably be set the same. Reading `:h timeout`, `:h timeoutlen` and `:h ttimeoutlen` should help you figure it out though. I'm pretty sure the reason is simply a workaround for quirks created by the difference between how GUI version of Vim handles this and how the terminal version of Vim handles this. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 7):

A quick workaround is using `<C-c>` instead, but you probably want to fix the timeout on `<Esc>`, which is caused by a mapping that starts with `<Esc>`, which makes Vim wait for `'timeoutlen'` to check whether the mapping is complete.

This does not necessarily need to be a "real" mapping; many terminal workarounds (e.g. to make certain keys work) advise to set up such a mapping. (Unfortunately, this is a difficult and complex issue.)

You can find the mapping via:

```
:verbose map <Esc>
```

Comment: when doing `<C-c>` there is no delay indeed. But I want to use `ESC`. I get `No mapping found`

Comment: Hm, it may also be caused by one of the `:set t_...` settings, but I don't know how to troubleshoot that.

Answer (score 3):

First try the accepted answer of adding the following to `.vimrc`

```
set timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=0
```

If that doesn't work check if you have any keybindings to `<esc>`

```
:imap <esc>
```

If you use tmux you also need:

```
set -sg escape-time 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no mapping bound to <ESC> globally or for Visual mode (calling :verbose vmap <ESC> gives no results) but there is still a significant delay when exiting Visual mode. Even on fresh installs with no vimrc the delay is present. Using <C-c> does exit visual mode without delay.

Since I don't like pressing <C-c> to exit any mode, I currently map <ESC> to <C-c> in visual mode. This exits visual mode using  <ESC> without any delay.

```
:vmap <ESC> <C-c>
```

Or put the following line in your vimrc

```
vnoremap <ESC> <C-c>
```

This will not work if you do have global or visual mode mappings bound to <ESC>.