# vim: remove delay when inserting text in visual block mode

Tags: vim

I often use the visual block mode (`Ctrl+V`) to insert text in different lines.

For instance, if I want to turn this:

```
Employee1, Address1, Phone1
Employee2, Address2, Phone2
Employee3, Address3, Phone3
Employee4, Address4, Phone4
Employee5, Address5, Phone5
```

into

```
Employee1, CompanyName, Address1, Phone1
Employee2, CompanyName, Address2, Phone2
Employee3, CompanyName, Address3, Phone3
Employee4, CompanyName, Address4, Phone4
Employee5, CompanyName, Address5, Phone5
```

I'll place the cursor on the semi-column after `Employee1`, then do

- `Ctrl+V` (enter visual block mode)
- `4j` (select the 4 following columns)
- `I` (enter Insert mode)
- `, CompanyName`
- `Esc`

Then, **about 1 second after**, all the lines are edited.

My question is: why this 1 second delay? Is it possible to remove it? Even better: could it be possible to have a real time editing, much like SublimeText multiple selection mode?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550100/exit-visual-mode-without-delay

Comment: Thanks a lot! I missed this thread. It indeed solves my problem.